# Is Deployment of Queues not supported from sfdx CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, cli

While deploying queues from vs code using sfdx cli, I'm getting below error:

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  The specified metadata type is unsupported: [queues]
```

It seems it's not supported.

Comment: Where is your metadata coming from ? The expected metadata api name is Queue, not queues.

Comment: Likewise, this contains good [info](https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48) for supported metadata types with regards to various situations. Queue seems to be supported for source tracking and metadata API so I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, queues are supported.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/queues
```

The expected file name format is:

```
Default.queue-meta.xml
```

And the expected contents should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Queue xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <doesSendEmailToMembers>false</doesSendEmailToMembers>
    <name>Default</name>
    <queueSobject>
        <sobjectType>Case</sobjectType>
    </queueSobject>
</Queue>
```

You'll want to refer to the Metadata API documentation for details.